# Thermal de Broglie wave length

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics

If we refer to this wiki page [thermal de Broglie wave length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_de_Broglie_wavelength), we can see there are two expressions. One is derived using equipartition theorem, which makes perfect sense. The other one used $\pi kT$ as the kinetic energy for a free particle, without explaining why it it so. Could anyone help me out here? Thanks.

Edit: $k$ is the Boltzmann constant and $T$ is the temperature.

Comment: Please just edit your question to say what  k and t represent. I guess k is bolstzman constant and t is temperature but I suggest you put that clearly in your question. Thanks

Comment: Hmm... It's not very clear to me what that Wikipedian means... did you check the reference they give--the Kittel book?